# Understanding java array initialisation using shift operator

Tags: java, arrays, bit-manipulation

I know that the max size that any array in java is Integer.maxValue. Because Arrays are int indexed. But I know, we also can initialize array using shift operator. I tried it but it throws weird output.

```
        int arr[] = new int[1<<5];
        System.out.println(arr.length);
        arr = new int[1<<10];
        System.out.println(arr.length);
        arr = new int[1<<20];
        System.out.println(arr.length);
        arr = new int[1<<25];
        System.out.println(arr.length);
        arr = new int[1<<40];
        System.out.println(arr.length);
        arr = new int[1<<111];
        System.out.println(arr.length);
```

I have expected at every n times shifted the resultant size of an array will be 2^n.

### But the output is following -

```
32
1024
1048576
33554432
256
32768
```

So if is there any other way to initialize array like this in proper size allocation, can be able to initialize an array with size 2^100 by shifting 1 100 times?

Comment: `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is also the max value that can be stored in an int array (not just the max index).

Comment: print out `1 << 40`, not related to array  at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You see that `System.out.println(1 << 40);` prints `256` because of overflow. In Java `int` overflows so `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` equals to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

You can try to do something like this:

```
int[] arr = new int[1 << 100];
```

But because both operands are of type `int` then the result will also be `int`. And due to overflow it will be not 2^100 but 16.

If you try to make JVM to convert result to `long` doing the following

```
int[] arr = new int[1L << 100];
```

You will get compilation error because length of array should be of type `int`.

Comment: little correction `1L >> 100` is just zero, probably meant `1L << 100`

Comment: So basically we cannot create arrays with size more than that of integer max , is there any way to create array of size more than that ?

Comment: @AashishPawar there is no way. And BTW why do you need it? You can use `HashMap<Long, Integer>` if you need kind of very very large array with constant access by index. Also int array with N elements will immediately allocate `N*4` bytes in heap. So for a large array you will need a lot of RAM